# ios Coredata large set insert

Tags: ios, core-data, insert, save, bulkinsert

hey i am stuck with the same problem for days , time for insert increases gradually and in lower ipads it also crashes with memory problem .To insert 20k records it takes 4-5 minutes.Will background thread improve efficieny. ? Is there anyway i can optimize this. Please help out if you can.

```
  +(BOOL) addObjectToProfessionalsDBWithDict:(NSArray*)profArray{

if (!([profArray count]>0 && profArray )) {
    return NO;
}

NSManagedObjectContext *thisContext=[self getManagedObjectContext];


for (int i=0; i<[profArray count]; i++) {
  NSManagedObject *professionalDBObject = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ProfessionalsDB"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:thisContext];//initWithDictionary:objectDict];        NSMutableDictionary * objectDict=[profArray objectAtIndex:i];
 [professionalDBObject setValue:[objectDict valueForKey:@"Degree"] forKey:@"degree"];
[professionalDBObject setValue:[objectDict valueForKey:@"First_Name"] 
  // and 10 more  values  

     if(i%500==0){
        NSError *error;
        NSLog(@"saved rec nu %d",i);
        if (![thisContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return NO;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"data saved");

        }

         [thisContext reset];


   }

}



[prefs setInteger:numOfRecords forKey:@"numberOfRecords"];
NSError *error;


if (![thisContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was taking around 4 minutes to store 20k records. I have brought it down to 8seconds(it was really tricky!) with the following code:

```
  +(NSManagedObjectContext*)getInsertContext{
NSManagedObjectContext *thisContext=[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
AppDelegate *delegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [delegate persistentStoreCoordinator];
[thisContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
[thisContext setUndoManager:nil];

return thisContext;
```

}

on every 1000 records i save in this context, after saving reset and get a new context again:

```
    [thisContext reset];
        thisContext=[self getInsertContext];
```

Comment: I think your performance boost is mainly the `nil` undo manager. That is standard practice in case of large imports with child contexts (it is mentioned in the Core Data Programming Guide).

Comment: Yes thats the main thing there. The above code boosts the performance as large data is not bloated in a single context.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in principle with inserting the seed data into the database at startup. Copying ready-made Core Data databases is certainly fast, but also cumbersome to prepare and keep updated.

Here are some ideas:

1) Rewrite the for loop so that you iterate through the batches and have an inner loop iterating through the records. Enclose both loops into separate `@autoreleasepool` brackets.

2) Consider changing `valueForKey` to `objectForKey` when retrieving the value from the dictionary. The difference is subtle, but important.

3) Clarify where your `thisContext` comes from. Is it the apps's main context or a child context. In the latter case the save does not actually write to the database until the parent also saves.

4) Consider the `performBlock` API of managed object context which gives you additional thread and memory insulation.

Comment: It would increase a minimal performance. However i have figured it out, answered below.

Comment: It worked for me like a charm for 12,000 records. It took around 15 seconds for me..

Answer (score 0):

You should ship with this DB already created in your bundle.

Comment: I get the data from from an request in form of JSON. I have found the solution below.