# iOS, Core Data: Memory Issues

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data, memory

I am converting my old huge sqlite database into core data and now I face the issue with memory.

```
-(void)linkCoinsToCoinagesInPeriods
{
DBAccess *acc=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
NSFetchRequest *coinagesFetch=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Coinage"];
NSArray *coinages=[_context executeFetchRequest:coinagesFetch error:nil]; // 2000+ items

for(Coinage *coinage in coinages)
{
    //retrieving different quantity of int objects less then 200 from database

    NSMutableArray *coinsArr=[acc returnKMListFromCoinageCell:1 period:coinage.uID.intValue];

    for(dbType *obj in coinsArr)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *coinsFetch=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Coin"];
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uID=%@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:obj.kmID]];
        coinsFetch.predicate=predicate;
        NSArray *coins=[_context executeFetchRequest:coinsFetch error:nil];
        for(Coin *coin in coins)
        {
            coin.coinage=coinage;
            NSLog(@"Linked coin to coinage: %@ -> %@",coin.uID, coinage.name);
        }
        coinsFetch=nil;
    }
    coinsArr=nil;
    [self saveContext];

}
}
```

at the same time I start running this method my processor shows 97% and memory consumption runs about 108.1 MB after the first minute.

Finally, Xcode throws me:

CoreData: error: (21) I/O error for database at /Users/ia/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/C5CCADE1-9FDD-4A03-BC44-FAD1C16DB0EF/Documents/Catalog/wci.sqlite.  SQLite error code:21, 'unable to open database file'

Frankly I can't find flaws in my code. Recently, I wrote the similar methods and memory was about 50MB after inserting 20000 objects. Any help? Thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550873/ios-coredata-large-set-insert . Refer my answer , accept if it helps you.

Comment: Not quite helped, but hell good idea is reseting context after N of inserts. I would accept your answer, but first you should submit one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ios Coredata large set insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550873/ios-coredata-large-set-insert)

[thisContext setUndoManager:nil];
This is the catch line. UndoManager takes lot of memory . You dont need undo manager when you insert , setting this to null would reduce you memory + increase your insertion to a great extent.

Comment: Thanks. UndoManager is useless in this case.